# Adjusting row height if tables in word using vba

Tags: vba, ms-word, row-height

I have a template based on the repetition of two pages with two different tables. I am working on a macro to adjust the row heights of these tables throughout the document so that the row heights are the same. Sometimes the tables stay on the page, sometimes it does overflows continuously onto a new page.

I have been trying a few different ways and the below is the closest I have come to getting it to work. Below gets the actual row height by looking at the position against the document. The issue I am having is that the tables are crossing pages and so keeps showing an error when it gets to a row on the next page. The error is 'The measurement must be between 0 pt and 1584 pt.'

This is the code I am currently using:

```
A = 1
B = 2

While B <= ActiveDocument.Tables.Count

Set T1 = ActiveDocument.Tables(A)
Set T2 = ActiveDocument.Tables(B)

Set R1 = T1.Rows
Set R2 = T2.Rows

Set C1 = T1.Columns
Set C2 = T2.Columns

For i = 1 To R1.Count()
   If i = R1.Count() Then
   Else
      H1 = T1.Rows(i + 1).Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) _
    - T1.Rows(i).Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
      H2 = T2.Rows(i + 1).Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) _
    - T2.Rows(i).Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)

      If H1 > 0 Or H1 < 1584 Or H2 > 0 Or H2 < 1584 Then
         If H1 > H2 Then
            R2(i).Height = H1
         Else
            R1(i).Height = H2
         End If
      End If
   End If

Next

A = A + 1
B = B + 2
Wend
```

I have also tried setting the height using the below, which doesn't work in this case as it only gets the default height of the row and not the actual height.

```
H1 = R1(i).Height
H2 = R2(i).Height
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Its really confusing. Can you correctly format the code with right Indentation ?

Comment: Is it correct that the problem is only appearing when the row *content* breaks across pages? If the break is at the end of a complete row, the problem doesn't occur? In that case, disallow the behavior for the duration of the code: `R1.AllowBreakAcrossPages = false : R2.AllowBreakAcrossPages = false`. After the code has run this can be switched back...

Comment: That's right Cindy, it is only happening when the row content breaks across pages. So should I start this in the foreach and then switch it back after the loop do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who helped. I ended up resolving this by using the following code and making the page of the document extremely long. Not ideal, but worked.

```
Sub rowHeight()
A = 2
B = 4

While B <= ActiveDocument.Tables.Count

Set T1 = ActiveDocument.Tables(A)
Set T2 = ActiveDocument.Tables(B)

Set r1 = T1.Rows
Set r2 = T2.Rows

Set C1 = T1.Columns
Set C2 = T2.Columns

On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To r1.Count()

If i = r1.Count() Then
Else
H1 = T1.Rows(i + 1).Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) _
    - T1.Rows(i).Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
H2 = T2.Rows(i + 1).Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) _
    - T2.Rows(i).Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
'H1 = R1(i).Height
'H2 = R2(i).Height
If H1 > 0 & H1 < 1584 & H2 > 0 & H2 < 1584 Then
If H1 > H2 Then
r2(i).Height = H1
Else
r1(i).Height = H2
End If
End If
End If

Next

A = A + 4
B = B + 4
Wend

End Sub
```